# Scrolling UITableView in iOS 9 results in overlapped labels

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, ios9, xcode7

After upgrading to Xcode 7 and iOS 9 beta, I am getting this error in one of my UITableViews. Whenever I scroll, my second label overlaps the first label in most of the cells. What is weird is that two of the current cells don't have this issue. See pictures for details.

[image: Normal Picture]

[image: Not Normal Picture]

[image: Some screwed up]

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    namesArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    locationsArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)


    let query = PFQuery(className: "Schools")
    // query.whereKey(key: String, containedIn: [AnyObject])

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            query.orderByAscending("schoolName")

            if let objects = query.findObjects() as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                    self.namesArray.append(object.valueForKey("schoolName") as! String)
                    self.locationsArray.append(object.valueForKey("schoolLocation") as! String)   
                    self.schoolTable.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Shit, it didn't work...")
        }
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:ChangeSchoolListTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! ChangeSchoolListTableViewCell

    if namesArray.count > 0 {
        cell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.locationLabel.text = locationsArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

class ChangeSchoolListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var locationLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screen short with constrains you are using in the cell?

Comment: @AndrewRomanov I have the same problem, did you fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, I've not. But I can try find the solution if you share example project with it problem (I can't reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding one label over another in the table. You need to add one label and reuse it instead of adding another label. The solution is to use a custom UITableViewCell subclass. Also it will be helpful if you show the code of UITableView methods.

Comment: I added the relevant code. They are two separate labels, and it is using a custom class. How would I use one label and reuse it? Can you take me through that, i've never done that before / had the need to.

Comment: Please show your ChangeSchoolListTableViewCell class.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you call *reloadData* from a background thread. If it is so, then it is a main problem, to solve it, you should call *reloadData* from the main thread. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985716/in-swift-how-to-call-method-with-parameters-on-gcd-main-thread) how to call a block of code on the main thread from the background thread.

Comment: I am not sure what this means. Also, I have basically an identical view controller and class that presents the same data, and it is not presenting a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove subviews of uitableviewcell's contentview before adding subviews.