# UITableView froze after tapping cell sometimes

Tags: ios, uitableview

Has somebody met this problem before? Just normally using one tableview, no huge computing, no time costing UI to display. Ordinary tableview with simple cells there. Tap one cell and sometimes (very small possibility but happens, really annoying) the whole UI will froze, and the only way to solve it is to restart app. Really weird.

Comment: reproducible in a simple new project or is it specific to yours ?

Comment: check asyc calls and the main queue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985716/in-swift-how-to-call-method-with-parameters-on-gcd-main-thread)

Comment: sorry, not yet, hard to reproduce but sometimes during testing, this issue would popup.

Comment: no asyc calls, very basic use.

Comment: Show us all your tableview-related code, from creation to deallocation (if any). You're probably doing something wrong that you wouldn't know about, hopefully.