# Swift Present View Controller After Succeeded Touch ID Authentication

Tags: swift, touch-id

I want to present a view Controller after the user Authenticates with Touch ID, here is my code and the error i am getting, I have no idea how to solve it[image]

and the console Shows [image]

Comment: The error clearly states that you are trying to do something that should be done on main thread only. The closure in which you are trying to present your VC must be running on a thread other than main thread, hence the error. You need to get hold of main thread before preseting your VC.

Comment: any idea how to do it?

Comment: You can use [GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985716/in-swift-how-to-call-method-with-parameters-on-gcd-main-thread) or [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue)

Comment: Thanks a lot! it has finally worked with OperationQueue.main.addOperation, Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to access main thread.try this.

For Swift 2.3

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    //place your code to push viewController
}
```

For Swift 3

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //place your code to push viewController
}
```