# WebRTC [UIView renderFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I have installed pod 'WebRTC' for audio/video calling in my app. In storyboard I have two UIView with class "RTCVideoRenderer". Below is my code. I'm following [this](https://hackernoon.com/swiftywebrtc-789936b0e39b)

```
func configureClient() {
    let iceServers = RTCIceServer.init(urlStrings: [stunServer])
    let client = RTCClient.init(iceServers: [iceServers], videoCall: true)
    client.delegate = self
    self.client = client
    client.startConnection()
}

extension ViewController: RTCClientDelegate {
func rtcClient(client: RTCClient, didCreateLocalCapturer capturer: RTCCameraVideoCapturer) {
    let settingsModel = RTCCapturerSettingsModel()
    self.captureController = RTCCapturer.init(withCapturer: capturer, settingsModel: settingsModel)
    captureController.startCapture()
}

func rtcClient(client: RTCClient, didGenerateIceCandidate iceCandidate: RTCIceCandidate) {
    print("iceCandidate generated")
}

func rtcClient(client: RTCClient, didReceiveLocalVideoTrack localVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        localVideoTrack.add(self.localVideoView)
        self.localVideoTrack = localVideoTrack
    }
}

func rtcClient(client: RTCClient, startCallWithSdp sdp: String) {
    print("SDP generated")
}

func rtcClient(client: RTCClient, didReceiveRemoteVideoTrack remoteVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        remoteVideoTrack.add(self.remoteVideoView)
        self.remoteVideoTrack = remoteVideoTrack
    }
}

func rtcClient(client : RTCClient, didReceiveError error: Error) {
    print("Error Received: \(error)")
}
}
```

This is crashing with errors:

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView setSize:]
>   PID: 9951, TID: 2583661, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.avfoundation.videodataoutput.bufferqueue, QoS: 0
>
> [UIView renderFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101501840
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView renderFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101501840'

Comment: try to call the function in the main thread. dispatch.main

Comment: I have called configureClient() method on main thread. But still the same. any other method you are talking about?

Comment: Please read this post. probably you will understand better how to call in functions in the main thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985716/in-swift-how-to-call-method-with-parameters-on-gcd-main-thread

Comment: @taratandel yes I have called the same way.