# How to print a pdf file from URL using UIPrintInteractionController asynchronously?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

In my app I have an option to print delivery note. When I tap this option, I receive a response from server with a url (url of a PDF file). As soon as the response is received, the app navigate to a screen which contains a button to perform a printing action.
Everything works ok until here. But when I tap the print button, the view gets frozen. I receive warning, that it is a synchronous url loading which causes app's ui unresponsive. It suggests to use some Asynchronous url loading like URLSession.
But I have no idea how to use it in this case.
Any help would be appreciated. I have provided code sample below.

```
public enum PrintingResult {
  case success
  case failure(Error)
  case userCancelled
}

public func presentPrintInteractionController(url: URL?, jobName: String? = nil, completion: ((PrintingResult) -> Void)? = nil) {
  let printController = UIPrintInteractionController()
  let printInfo = UIPrintInfo.printInfo()
  if let jobName = jobName {
    printInfo.jobName = jobName
  }
  printController.printInfo = printInfo

  if let url = url {
    printController.printingItem = url
  }
  printController.present(animated: true) { _, completed, error in
    guard let completion = completion else { return }
    if completed {
        completion(.success)
    } else {
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
        } else {
            completion(.userCancelled)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReportView: View {
   var reportUrl: String

   init(reportUrl: String) {
      self.reportUrl = reportUrl
   }

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
          Button {
            presentPrintInteractionController(url: URL(string: reportUrl), jobName: "Print a pdf report") { result in
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    print("Print Successful")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                case .userCancelled:
                    print("Printing job cancelled.")
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Print")
        }
     }
  }
}

struct ReportView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       ReportView(reportUrl: "")
   }
}
```

[image: This is the warning]

Comment: @ArashEtemad I tried wrapping printController.present closer with DispatchQueue.main.async {}. But it is still same. Doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Swift how to call method with parameters on GCD main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985716/in-swift-how-to-call-method-with-parameters-on-gcd-main-thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `UIPrintInteractionController` is trying to fetch data from the remote URL synchronously. One way to solve this would be to fetch the data asynchronously *yourself*, and the give the `Data` to the `UIPrintInteractionController`.

The basic idea is:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url)) { data, response, error in
    // do some error handling...
    
    printController.printingItem = data
    
    printController.present(animated: true) { _, completed, error in
        // call your completion handler here...
    }
}.resume()
```

I'd suggest turning `presentPrintInteractionController` into an `async throws` function, and get rid of the completion handler parameter.

It is much less nested this way.

```
// you don't need to wrap the built-in errors that can be thrown
// so the only case left is userCancelled.
// perhaps consider renaming this 
public enum PrintingResult: Error {
  case userCancelled
}

// assuming this is a global function, you'd need @MainActor
@MainActor
public func presentPrintInteractionController(url: URL?, jobName: String? = nil) async throws {
    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController()
    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo.printInfo()
    if let jobName = jobName {
        printInfo.jobName = jobName
    }
    printController.printInfo = printInfo

    if let url = url {
        // fetching the data asynchronously
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        // you might add some error handling here by inspecting response
        printController.printingItem = data
    }
    
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        printController.present(animated: true) { _, completed, error in
            if completed {
                continuation.resume()
            } else if let e = error {
                continuation.resume(with: .failure(e))
            } else {
                continuation.resume(with: .failure(PrintingResult.userCancelled))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use `do...catch` in your `Button` code to handle the three cases:

```
Button {
    Task {
        do {
            try await presentPrintInteractionController(url: URL(string: reportUrl), jobName: "Print a pdf report")
            print("Print Successful")
        } catch PrintingResult.userCancelled {
            print("Printing job cancelled.")
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
} label: {
    Text("Print")
}
```